# How to get Protractor to reload the DOM without reloading the browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriver-io

How to get Protractor to reload the DOM without reloading the browser?

I have a web app that loads completely and then 5 seconds later it dynamically adds a survey to the page and the DOM changes.    My Protractor test is unable to find any of the elements on the survey popup (Qualtrics survey on Angular app), including the close button.

So, how can I get Protractor to re-read the DOM so that it knows about the survey popup?

Reloading the page or re-navigating to the same URI is NOT an option because it will reset the application and the page state is lost and the survey will disappear.

Using [waitForAngularEnabled](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngularEnabled) will not work because the DOM changes again after a 5-second timer.

For example, neither of these worked:

```
isSurveyDialog() {
  return element(by.css('div.QSIPopOver')).isPresent() as Promise<boolean>;
}

isSurveyDialog() {
  const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  return browser.wait(EC.presenceOf($('.QSIPopOver')), 10000) as Promise<boolean>;
}
```

Is there a lower-level "webdriver js" way to do this?

EDIT:
explanation of symptom: AFTER the page has finished loaded , a few seconds later, the HTML elements circled in RED are dynamically added to the DOM without a page refresh.
[image]

Comment: you shouldn't need to reload the page for this. this might be because your dialog is in an iframe. Can you check that? essentially see if there is an `iframe` html tag anywhere, if yes, is your dialog inside of this iframe

Comment: It's not an iframe.  Neither is it a hidden-DOM.   It is a  DOM-modification event that happens without reloading the page that adds a new element into the html BODY.   This is something common to how Qualtrics survey works, which I am not an expert at.

Comment: is there a way for me  to see this HTML?

Comment: Maybe i could attach an animated GIF.  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: You dont need to reload the page in order to let protractor know about existence of the popup, to clear that out of the way

Comment: show me an example of how you run the code to handle the popup and what the error is

Comment: Could you do something like `await browser.executeScript('location.reload()')`?

Comment: In this case I cannot force a reload because it will nuke the page state and I will lose the dialog.

Comment: Looks like Protractor is no longer supported after Angular 14, and so I will probably switch to using Cypress anyway.